# how to orderby before groupby columns products table and show unique and available products

Tags: php, laravel, subquery, sql-order-by

I've a problem in laravel query:

I wanna to order by before group by of same columns,
for example:

**Products table**

```
id ....... cat_id ....... color_id ....... count<br>
---------------------------------------------------------<br>
1 ........... 27 ............... 3 ............... 0
<br>
2 ........... 27 ............... 7 ................ 3
<br>
3 ........... 27 ............... 3 ................ 10
<br>
4 ........... 27 ............... 3 ................ 2
```

now: I wanna down result with first **orderby 'count'** so **groupby 'cat_id,color_id'**:

```
id ....... cat_id ....... color_id ....... count<br>
---------------------------------------------------------<br>
3 ........... 27 ............... 3 ............... 10
<br>
2 ........... 27 ............... 7 ................ 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Query looks like

```
SELECT id, cat_id, color_id, count FROM products
```

and `count` is a value from the DB, you can just combine `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` statements:

```
SELECT id, cat_id, color_id, count FROM products GROUP BY cat_id, color_id ORDER BY count
```

With this Query a lot of results are **lost**. If you want to combine the values for lets say `count` you could use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT id, cat_id, color_id, GROUP_CONCAT(count) FROM products GROUP BY cat_id, color_id ORDER BY count
```

With this Query, you will still get all relevant information, but for every entry in columns `cat_id` and `color_id` you will get a comma-seperateted string of the values for `count`.

Here some links for further information from w3schools:

- [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)
- [ORDER BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
select pr_l.* 
from products pr_l
inner join (
     select 
     cat_id, color_id,max(count) as count 
     from products
     group by `cat_id`,`color_id`
  ) pr_r
on pr_l.count = pr_r.count and pr_l.cat_id = pr_r.cat_id and  pr_l.color_id = pr_r.color_id   
order by count desc
```

normally 'order by' before 'group by' is not working . so that i have used inner join for products table

left products table has all records and right products table has maximum count row with group by cat_id and color_id

for laravel sql syntax

```
$products = $products->select(DB::raw('pr_l.*'))->from(
DB::raw('inner join (
 select 
 cat_id, color_id,max(count) as count 
 from products
 group by `cat_id`,`color_id`
) pr_r')
)->where(pr_l.count = pr_r.count and pr_l.cat_id = pr_r.cat_id and  pr_l.color_id =   pr_r.color_id)->orderBy('count', 'desc');
```

Answer (score -1):

how to convert:

```
select l.* 
from products l
inner join (
     select 
     cat_id, color_id,max(count) as count 
     from products
     group by `cat_id`,`color_id`
  ) r
on l.count = r.count and l.cat_id = r.cat_id and  l.color_id = r.color_id   
order by count desc
```

to laravel elequent syntax looklike down:

```
$products = $products->select(DB::raw('l.*'))->from(
    DB::raw('inner join (
     select 
     cat_id, color_id,max(count) as count 
     from products
     group by `cat_id`,`color_id`
  ) r')
)->where(l.count = r.count and l.cat_id = r.cat_id and  l.color_id = r.color_id)->groupBy(['products_id','color'])->orderBy('count', 'desc');
```